# MongoDB DeleteMany except latest document group by User

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Below is an example of documents i have in a collection. I want to delete all the duplicate documents except for the one that has the latest revision number filtered by user and grouped by guid

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f263e6"),
    guid: 1,
    revision: 1,
    user:1
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f263e7"),
    guid: 1,
    revision: 2,
    user:1
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f264d0"),
    guid: 2,
    revision: 5,
    user:1
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f264d1"),
    guid: 1,
    revision: 5,
    user:1
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f264d2"),
    guid: 3,
    revision: 5,
    user:2
  }
]
```

Expect output should delete following documents
For user : 1

```
--  _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f263e6"),
--  _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f263e7"),
--  _id: ObjectId("5e8e2d28ca6e660006f264d0"),
```

For user : 2
None

I have tried below query it works but fails in scenario when i have same guid and same revision number. In case both are same then anyone can be deleted

```
db.collection.find({guid:1,revision:1}).sort({revision:-1}).forEach(function(doc){
   console.log(db.collection.deleteMany({revision:{$lt:doc.revision}, guid:doc.guid}));
})
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Step 1**

Get the documents that are lastly revised

```
  let data = await db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $sort: {
          user: 1,
          guid: 1,
          revision: -1
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            guid: "$guid",
            user: "$user"
          },
          id: {
            $first: "$_id"
          },
          guid: {
            $first: "$guid"
          },
          user: {
            $first: "$user"
          },
          revision: {
            $first: {
              $max: "$revision"
            }
          },
          doc: {
            $last: "$$ROOT"
          }
        },
        
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: "$id",
          guid: 1,
          revision: 1,
          user: 1
        }
      },
       
    ])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QSB9a0aARCA)

**Step 2**

Get the _ids of the resultant data

```
x = data.map(item=>item._id);
```

**Step 3**

Delete documents other than `x`

```
db1.deleteMany({ "_id": { $nin: x } });
```

**Option 2 for Single query to do the same task**

```
  let data = await db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $sort: {
          user: 1,
          guid: 1,
          revision: -1
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            guid: "$guid",
            user: "$user"
          },
          id: {
            $first: "$_id"
          },
          guid: {
            $first: "$guid"
          },
          user: {
            $first: "$user"
          },
          revision: {
            $first: {
              $max: "$revision"
            }
          },
          doc: {
            $last: "$$ROOT"
          }
        },
        
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: "$id",
          guid: 1,
          revision: 1,
          user: 1
        }
      },
        { $out: "temp1" } // temp1 is the collection name
    ])
```

Comment: Thank you this is good help. Can you please advise how i can run this in mongo shell directly

Comment: > db
test
> use temp_db
switched to db temp_db
> db.temp1.aggregate([
...         {
...             $sort: {
...                 user: 1,
...                 guid: 1,
...                 revision: -1
...      
...         { $out: "temp1" }
...     ])
>

Comment: temp_db is my dbName and temp1 is the collection name

Comment: sorry, i wanted to ask the shell equivalent for x = data.map(item=>item._id);

Comment: if you want to go for shell... go for option 2. so that you dont have to query two times